# Deploy Cloud9 IDE to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, cloud9-ide

I"m trying to deploy a simple Node.JS app to Heroku from Cloud9, and I can't seem to be able to find the "Deploy" button to deploy it to Heroku. Is this feature present on Heroku?

[http://imgur.com/mrEvDz1](https://imgur.com/mrEvDz1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current Cloud9 release we do not have a UI for deployment yet, but we're going to add those features soon. They have been flaky at times and we really want to offer things that work.

Until then, I'd recommend using the deployment tools straight from the command line in the Terminal - see our documentation site for details: https://docs.c9.io/deploying_via_cli.html .

Regarding Heroku, deploying via the terminal is not too difficult, although I would have preferred not to disappoint you. All steps are explained in the link below, you can start at step 3 because the Heroku tool belt should already be installed.

Refer: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart

Comment: Hi, do you know when this feature will be added? Thanks!

Comment: The Heroku integration will be part of a bigger release. Hopefully we should have that Q1 2015. We learned the hard way to be vague about deadlines. It's hard to make concrete promises/predictions like that. See also https://www.groovehq.com/blog/feature-release-dates :)